# Eclipse CDT project fails to include moved header file after system upgrade

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, include

I have a CMake project which I have so far built successfully with Eclipse. (Detailed setup instructions for that project [here](https://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Eclipse).) That was with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and Eclipse Luna.

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu MATE 18.04. Since Eclipse would no longer start (presumably due to compatibility issues with the new OpenJDK version), I figured it was time to upgrade to Oxygen.

Once I had Eclipse Oxygen and all add-ons set up, I opened the workspace and tried to build the project. It failed with the following message:

```
/home/user149408/src/navit/navit/binding/python/common.h:20:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I grep’ed and found the header file at `/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h`. I checked the project properties under **C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols** and noticed it had an entry for `/usr/include/python3.5m`, so I changed that to reflect the current path.

But even after that, the project fails to build with the same error message. I have tried the following:

- Re-run `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ~/src/navit`
- Refresh the project
- Clean the project
- Build again

When I try to build the project with CMake on the command line, it builds without errors. What’s wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `cmake` does not re-evaluate everything but relies on some cached data from the first run.

In the project directory (in the workspace), I deleted the following two files:

```
.cproject
CMakeCache.txt
```

Then I re-ran `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ~/src/navit`, started Eclipse, refreshed the project, cleaned and built it.

This time the build goes through with no errors. The app still throws an error about a missing GTK module, but that also happens with the command line build and is almost certainly a different issue.

---

Update: After running into various other issues, I learned that CMake’s Eclipse project generator appears to be unmaintained and error-prone, the recommendation being to use cmake4eclipse (available on Eclipse Marketplace) instead. If you are having the issue I described above, consider migrating.